# Is it possible to disable translation for a TYPO3 TCA record

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x, typo3-tca

Could anybody help me to sort out this issue?
I want to disable the translation for a table. So that extbase will get all the records without considering the language uid. (Setting -1 (ALL) currently fix)

Ideally I need to force sys_language_uid = -1 (ALL) For a Inline reference records. The parent record always has translations and the inline records dont have translations. Is there any standard way to force this?.

I've added `'l10n_mode' => 'exclude',` to the parent TCA against the referenced table column. So that the referenced TCA inline fields wont be shown against the parent TCA record during the localization view of the parent TCA record.